# How to persist a computed property SwiftUI 2.0 Xcode 12.3

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I am trying to update and persist subtotal in my app when the user increments using a stepper

Current App flow:

- The user enters data in form data gets saved to core data.
- an @FetchRequest gets the data from core data.
- In a list, the core data entities are iterated over and data is passed to a view
- In the view, a computed property gets and updates the subtotal locally in view only.
- The user by tapping a stepper can increment or decrement and subtotal gets displayed

Question: How to constantly update subtotal and persist so I can access in another view to total all subtotals and reset each instance of the subtotal

What I have tried:

```
import SwiftUI

struct testView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: WindowCounter.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
        
        NSSortDescriptor(
            keyPath: \WindowCounter.userOrder,
            ascending: true),
        NSSortDescriptor(
            keyPath:\WindowCounter.subtotal,
            ascending: true )
    ]) var windows: FetchedResults<WindowCounter>
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @ObservedObject var estimatorData: EstimatorViewModel
    
    var id: UUID
    @State var price: Double
    @State var qty: Int
    @State var subtotal: Double
    
    var getSubtotal: String {
        let result = (Double(qty) * price)
        return String(format: " %.2f", result)
    }
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //.....
            HStack {
                // ....
                Text("Subtotal $ \(getSubtotal)")
                    .foregroundColor(Color("Primary"))
                    .onChange(of: getSubtotal) { newValue in
                        updateSubtotal(newSubTotal: getSubtotal)
                    }
                //....
            }
           
        }
    }
    // This I think after some comments I received
// is the wrong approach might be better to persist in another way.

    func updateSubtotal(newSubTotal: String) {
        print(newSubTotal)
     // Updated subtotal is in newSubtotal

        for window in windows {
            window.subtotal = Double(newSubTotal) ?? 0.00
        }
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A computed var by definition always updates because it is calculated on every read. You may want to read this guide to see how he did it. https://blckbirds.com/post/core-data-and-swiftui/ But the premise is all wrong. This should be abstracted into a persistence service agnostic to core data or firebase or json. if this is a commercial app. Otherwise changing databases will invalidate the entire thing.

Comment: Hi, @Ryan Thanks for the help it means a lot to me. 

I have read the blackbird tutorial may times. 

How would you suggest I abstract to a persistence service in SwiftUI?

Comment: I see in the blackbirds tutorial they are using 

viewContext.performAndWait {
            order.orderStatus = newStatus
            try? viewContext.save()
        }

Comment: Mike and Caio at Essential Developer have some good lectures on composing apps from independent modules. The persistence and logic of your app will be the same for any UI framework. Most every SwiftUI tutorial demonstrates poor coding practices, which I think actually slows learning, ingrains unsustainable habits, and makes it seem like “architecture” is “hard” when it really could be taught as second nature without $10 words. *soap box*

Comment: Sounds like there’s an async call in that, which makes sense. The database is going to operate at its own speed. That’s what a service will do... keep an in-memory model that updates immediately... and the service will separately decide the frequency with which to update the database. Why? (1) Internet connection speed might be slow or your update might be expensive and better batched together. (2) You may have no internet connection and then you’ll want to fallback to a local copy.

Comment: No internet involved in this app. I did check out the essential developer thanks

Comment: Maybe I don't need to write this property to core data as the user just needs to read it and it needs to persist. I just don't know SwiftUI well enough to know what approach to take or protocols to use

Comment: Core Data really is overkill unless you've got a lot of relationships between lots of items to query. Simply google persisting JSON. It'll be the same code. You'll add Codable conformance to your model objects and use JSONDecoder. You can search for tutorials that use JSONDecoder with generics, which will let you build a persistence module once and use it across your apps.